# apache cassandra replication_factor not working correctly

Tags: cassandra

I'm trying to learn apache cassandra, so I made a keyspace named `books3` with class of `simple strategy` and replication factor of `2`.I've read from [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/architecture/archDataDistributeReplication.html) that the first replica is placed on the node determined by the partitioner and additional replicas are placed on the next nodes clockwise in the ring without considering topology.

I have 3 nodes in my rack:

1. 192.168.0.2
2. 192.168.0.3
3. 192.168.0.5

I've created a table named users with some data in it.

The problem is, with the `replication_factor` of `2`, I have access to the data on all 3 nodes above.

Is there anything I'm wrong about?

Comment: When you say you can access the data on all 3 nodes, how do you test that? I assume you shutdown node1, node2 then connect to node3, etc.?

Comment: @AlanBoudreault now i get the idea, I was testing when all nodes were connected. Thanks for your comment

Comment: Did you solve the issue with Alan's comment? You should create an answer yourself and accept it so people know this question is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AlanBoudreault gave the idea, it doesn’t matter on which node you request for a data, thanks to gossip protocol you get the answer (if there is any).

And thats different with the fact that on which node(s) data are copied. I have a keyspace with replication factor of 2 and i get the data no matter on which node i write the query. But if I run the third node alone (the other two nodes are offline), My query doesn’t give me any data